# How can I determine the coordinates of graph vertices using only a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

If i have a weighted adjacency matrix for a graph, is it possible to determine the coordinates of the vertices of that graph if one unit of weight is equal to one unit of distance?

My intuition says that at least two vertices would have to be fixed, and you could only determine the position of vertices with at least degree two that form triangles, as the other "loose" vertices could exist anywhere on a radius equal to its weight, but even just being able to work out the position of the ones that form triangles would be useful.

Is there any algorithm or technique that could be useful to work this out?

I guess, to use an analogy (if i am not being too vague in my description), is that I can get a whole bunch of pieces of string with lengths corresponding to the edge weights. If i tie them all together so that the knots represent the vertices i should be able to stretch the net out so that all of the vertices are in some position in space, relative to eachother..

My question is: how can i do that algebraically/algorithmically, without using pieces of string?

Comment: It's certainly not unique, since you can transpose/translate/rotate your graph...

Comment: I know there wouldnt be a unique solution, but a method to work out any solution that is feasible would be very helpful.. just like in my string example, im sure there are many ways that i can move and contort the net while still maintaining a feasible solution; but i am interested in finding any feasible solution so it doesn't matter to me that it isn't unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem is usually known as 'graph layout'; specifically layout on a unit grid. There's a ton of stuff out there about layout, and to answer your implicit question - no, there is no guarantee of a unique layout for an arbitrary graph (even up to rotation).

For certain classes of graphs, there are unique embeddings in the plane (equivalent to drawings, in some sense). Polyhedra have unique embeddings, although to convert an embedding to a drawing you have to pick an outer face, which can make them look different.

More tricky are graphs that are non-planar - in other words, they have no embedding. You can of course draw them, but with lines that cross. Picking an embedding of a sub-graph such that the parent has a minimal number of crossings is still an open problem, IIRC.

All that said, your 'string' approach is basically spring layout, for which there are any number of libraries or descriptions of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful and in depth answer. I will do some reading on graph layout problems and see if i can find anything good. That open problem of finding a graph embedding such that there are minimal crossings that you mentioned looks interesting as well